# patching kernel (every update?)

Tags: kernel, updates, patch

I'm about to apply that famous patch that makes vgaarb see nvidia as a VGA device to the kernel.

But Linux releases a new kernel only every 2 month as I know. And Ubuntu kernel releases are even later.

*So is the above the only way to patch the new kernel every time?*

Comment: No, you can automate this task. Take a look at [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too short for an answer, but I'll risk it:

Yes, you have to patch the kernel every time. This is logical, and comparable with the update of proprietary modules, such as Nvidia. To automate patching, you could use [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS), as does Nvidia.